# Dates not binding in extjs 4.1 from js date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extjs4.1

I am having an issue binding to the date picker in ext js 4.1.

I'm using asp.net mvc to create my json feeds.

I have the following .net property

```
public DateTime? Created { get; set; }
```

When this is serialized into json i get the following

```
"Created":"\/Date(1346626800000)\/"
```

On extjs 4.1 model i have the following class property

```
  {
            mapping:'Created',
            name:'Created',
            type: 'date'
        },
```

in my field i have the following

```
  {
                            xtype:'datefield',
                            name:'Created',
                            fieldLabel:' Date',
                            format:'d/m/Y',
                            width: 350
                        },
```

Whats going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

in extjs4 ,you should specify the dateFormat in your store so Ext can parse it properly and you'll ensure it gets read ok.

```
   {name: 'Item1' , type : 'date', dateFormat :'MS'}
```

you can see [this](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Date) for available format strings.